# Getting Facebook's iframe to resize its height

Tags: css, facebook, iframe, height

I'm working on this [facebook app page](https://www.facebook.com/DonateToAcsExample/app_127502060729545).

The iframe's height is stuck at 800px, but the iframe's content is much taller. I googled around for ways to adjust the iframe's height and I ended up on [this facebook dev page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/).

and from that I came up with this...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    FB.Canvas.setSize();
</script>
```

But it's not working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think I may have gotten it working with this... http://pastebin.com/yadaE1kn

Comment: That code works for Chrome, but breaks in firefox :*( To get it working in FF you have to remove the css overflow:hidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
Fb.canvas.setAutoGrow()
```

see this reference 
    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/

that might be helpful.